# Remove Element from the linked list

Tags: linked-list

```
def removeKFromList(l, k):
    
    pointer = l
    while pointer:
        if pointer.next and pointer.next.value == k:
            pointer.next = pointer.next.next
        else:
            pointer = pointer.next
    
    if l and l.value == k:
        return l.next
    else:
        return l
```

In this code, why do I need to put
`pointer = pointer.next`
under else? Code does not work if I don't write this under else, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First realise that `pointer` is intended to reference the node that *precedes* the one that might need to be deleted.

Now if we find that the successor of `pointer` must be deleted, then we get in the `if` block. In that case the removal of the next node will make the node that comes *after that one*, the new successor of `pointer`. As we want to make the check (for deletion) also for that new successor, we should *not* move `pointer`, but just leave it like that. In the next iteration we will then correctly determine whether that new successor node must be deleted or not.

If we would have moved `pointer` with `pointer.next`, then `pointer` would refer to the new successor, but it would not be checked for removal (in the next iteration). It would escape the removal check!

Here is a visualisation of what can go wrong when we do `pointer = pointer.next` in that case.

Input: l = `[1,2,2,3]`, `k = 2`

```
  l
pointer
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

In the first iteration the condition `pointer.next.value == k` is true, and so the removal is performed with `pointer.next = pointer.next.next`, resulting in this situation:

```
  l
pointer
  ↓           ┌────────────────┐ 
┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │ │  │ value: 2  │ └> │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
│ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

If now we would do `pointer = pointer.next`, then we get this:

```
  l                                pointer
  ↓           ┌────────────────┐    ↓
┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │ │  │ value: 2  │ └> │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
│ next: ──────┘  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next:None │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

...and in the next iteration the `if` condition will not be about that node, but about the next, the one with value 3, and so the second occurrence of 2 will not be deleted!

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very thorough explanation! I understood it-- I really appreciate it:))